# Validate input field

Tags: javascript

i am trying to find the empty input fields!!!

```
    <div style="float: left; margin: 5px;">
    <p style="margin-left: 50%;">x</p>
    <input id="myInput1" type="number">
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; margin: 5px;">
        <p style="margin-left: 50%;">y</p>
        <input id="myInput2" type="number">
    </div>

    <button style="margin-top: 55px;" onclick="validate1()">some things</button>

     <script> 

    function validate1(){
    var one = document.getElementById("myInput1").value;
    var two = document.getElementById("myInput2").value;
    if(one == null)
    alert("missing data in x");
    else if (two == null)
    alert("missing data in y");
    else 
    alert("yes, it works");
}
       </script>
```

please help!:) it does not show if the input fields are empty
what is wrong???
i am trying to find out if the input fields are empty

Comment: Why `one == null`? Use `one === ""` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`one == null` tells you if `one` is `null` or `undefined`, but if the input field is empty, then `.value` is the empty string, not `null` nor `undefined`.

Instead, you should use something like

```
if(one === '') // compare with empty string directly, I recommend this

if(!one) // check if "falsy" (which for strings mean empty)

if(one.length === 0) // check if string has no length
```